# Design a Stack structure with allocating function

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement stack in C.

What I'm going for:

1. Design a **Stack** structure with **push** and **pop** functions for the implementation.
2. Create a **Memory** structure owns *number of block*, *block size*, and *stack* attributes.
   *Stack* attribute represents memory blocks. *Number of block* attribute represents the length of the stack. *Block size* represents the maximum value that each element in the stack can get.
3. Write an **allocate** function that takes a size parameter. If the given size is bigger than *block size* of the **Memory**, the allocation will be distributed to the different blocks in the stack attribute.

For example, calling `allocate(27)` updates the stack as:

```
allocate(27) = [10, 10, 7, 0, 0]
```

for a **Memory** with *number of block* = 5, *block size* = 10. The remaining of the elements which don't have maximum value can be sealed until the element is flushed. Therefore, the next allocation can start from next element position after 7 given above.

4. Write a deallocate function that flushes the last used block.

## My Work:

> First, created the structs:

- stack attribute represents memory blocks.
- number of block attribute represents the length of the stack.
- Block size represents the maximum value that each element in the stack can get.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // Provides function For memory locating. allocate & deallocate.
 
struct Stack {
    int top;
};

struct Memory{
    int stack;
    int number_of_block; // 5
    int block_size; // 10
};
```

Then I have tried to create allocate & push function but they are not working.

```
int main(){
    allocate(30);
    return 0;
}

int allocate(int size){

    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    struct Memory* memory = (struct Memory*)malloc(sizeof(struct Memory));
    memory->block_size = 10;
    stack->top = -1;
    memory->stack = (int*)malloc(memory->block_size * sizeof(int));

    struct Memory memory = {1, 5, 10};

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if(size > 10){
            size = size - 10; //27 - 10 = 17 -> 17 - 10 = 7
            push(stack, 10);
        }
    }
    if(size % 10 != 0){
        int size_mod = size % 10; //27 % 10 = 7
        push(stack, size_mod);
    }
}


void push(struct Stack* stack, struct Memory* memory, int item){
    if(stack->top == memory->block_size - 1){
        return;
    }
    memory->stack[++stack->top] = item;
    printf("%d ", item);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Memory` structure contains a pointer to the first block, as well as the number of blocks and the maximum size of each block. Each block then contains the data and a pointer to the next block, meaning all the blocks are stored in a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

The function `allocate` returns a pointer to the Memory structure created.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Block {
    int data;
    struct Block *next;
};

struct Memory {
    int block_count;
    int block_size;
    struct Block *head;
};

/* Push a new block onto the stack */
void push(struct Block **head, int data)
{
    struct Block *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    if (!new) {
        printf("Error: memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new->data = data;
    *head = new;
    /* `printf` is not needed */
    printf("%d\n", data);
}

/* Returns a pointer to the `Memory` structure */
struct Memory *allocate(int size)
{
    struct Memory *memory = malloc(sizeof *memory);
    if (!memory) {
        printf("Error: memory allocation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    memory->block_count = 5;
    memory->block_size = 10;

    struct Block *head = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < memory->block_count; ++i) {
        int data = 0;
        if (size > 10)
            data = 10;
        else if (size > 0)
            data = size;
        size -= data;
        push(&head, data);
    }
    memory->head = head;

    return memory;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Memory *memory = allocate(27);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And as you can see, you [don't need to cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605856/14947044), because it returns `void *`, which is automatically and safely promoted to any other pointer.